# If $G/H=K$, when will $G\cong H\times K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm bit confused here.

Take $G$ as the symmetry group of a square $G=\{e,a,b,c,d,f,g,h\}$ where

- $e$ is the identity
- $a$ is rotating by 180
- $b$ is rotating anti-clockwise by 90
- $c$ is rotating anti-clockwise by 270
- $d$ is reflection by one diagonal
- $f$ is reflection by another diagonal
- $g$ is reflection by the horizontal line
- $h$ is reflection by the vertical line

, $H = \{e,a\}$, where $H\cong Z_2$

, and $K=\{eH,bH,dH,gH\}$, where $K\cong Z_2\times Z_2$,

, we have $G/H=K$.

However, $G\cong H\times K$ does not hold, because some elements in $G$ has order 4, while all elements in $H\times K\cong (Z_2 \times Z_2)\times Z_2$ has order 2.

So if $G/H=K$, when will $G\cong H\times K$?

Comment: Your example is correct, which answers your question with a 'no'.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft so what kind of extra condition will Ensure $G\cong H\times K$?

Comment: You further need a subgroup of $G$ isomorphic to $K$, which is normal and intersects $H$ trivially.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension

Comment: It'd also be worth looking at the semidirect product.